# Display data from SQFlite into Grid List (Flutter)?

Tags: list, text, flutter, grid

I store in my SQFlite DB some instances about my `Pet` model class. After, I retrieve these info in my HomePage and I want to display the `name` of each element in a different Grid List element. I tried with this method:

```
     Container imageGrid(List<Pet> pets) {
    return Container(
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: List.generate(pets.length, (index) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
                children: pets
                    .map(
                      (pet) => Text(pet.name),
                ).toList(),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
```

but this displays **all the names** in each Grid element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this piece of code. You will see each name on each grid element.

```
return Center(
    child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[Text(pets[index].name)],
    ),
);
```